# Make menu on ActionBar stay open when I click on an item

Tags: java, android

I have a search feature for recipes and I want to include search filters for different allergies or diets. I have included this as an option on the action bar on the page. However, whenever I click on a checkbox, the menu disappears and I have to go click on the orange icon again to popup the menu and then click on another option. Is there a way where the menu can stay open so I can check multiple filters without the menu closing each time?

This is an picture of my filter section.

[image]

**checkable_test.xml**

```
<item android:id="@+id/action"
    android:title="@string/action_example"
    android:icon="@drawable/filter"
    app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom">

<menu>

<item android:title="Allergies">
    <menu>

        <group android:id="@+id/allergies"
            android:checkableBehavior="all">

            <item android:id="@+id/no_peanut"
                android:icon="@drawable/no_peanut"
                android:title="No Peanuts"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/no_sesame"
                android:icon="@drawable/no_sesame"
                android:title="No Sesame"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/no_dairy"
                android:title="No Dairy"
                android:icon="@drawable/no_milk"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/gluten_free"
                android:icon="@drawable/gluten_free"
                android:title="No Gluten"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/no_egg"
                android:icon="@drawable/no_eggs"
                android:title="No Egg"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/no_soy"
                android:icon="@drawable/no_soy"
                android:title="No Soy"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/no_seafood"
                android:icon="@drawable/no_crust"
                android:title="No Seafood"
                android:checkable="true"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

**Search.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.checkable_test, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.no_peanut:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.no_dairy:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.no_egg:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.no_seafood:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.no_sesame:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.no_soy:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.gluten_free:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Any solutions please?

Comment: Hey Theman, did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing all of the

```
return true;
```

into

```
return false;
```

Comment: tried this and it doesn't change anything, menu still disappears